# Gain and phase margin interpretation in control system

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, phase-margin

I have a unity feedback system with the open loop transfer function having the following bode plot:
[image]

As shown on the plot, the gain margin and phase margin are -27.4937dB and 75.0185 degrees.
And the respective gain crossover frequency(ω_gc) and phase crossover frequency(ω_pc) are 4.6090 and 0.4428 rad/s respectively.

My questions are:

1. Is the maximum time delay that the control output can input the plant calculated like this?:
   $$
   \frac{phaseMargin}{\omega_{gc}}=\frac{1.3093}{4.6090} = 0.2841 \ second
   $$
   I converted the phase margin into radians.
2. If we have a noise in the feedback path, oscillating at ω_gc, and the controller's output is delayed by more than 0.2841s, then this means that the system becomes unstable right?
3. If we have a noise in the feedback path, oscillating at a frequency higher than ω_gc, e.g. 1000 rad/s, what would be the minimum time delay to cause the system to become unstable?

Comment: Your phase graph seems weird: it looks like there are two zeroes, not showing up in the magnitude curve! Can you check if the phase graph is upside down and there is a right half plane zero?

Comment: Yes, the phase plot looks not good; please show us the test circuit.